# MySQL: str_to_date mess up the year

Tags: mysql

I trying to convert one of column name timeposted(varchar because some of the data has word like yesterday and today) using str_to_date function because I need to later retrieve the period of 3 months but somehow it went to change all the year into 2020 with any year found in timeposted.

Example:

1. 09-03-2005 after convert become 09-03-2020
2. 31-09-2011 after convert become 31-03-2020

My sql:

```
select str_to_date(REPLACE(LEFT(timeposted, LOCATE(' ', timeposted)), ',', ''), '%d-%m-%y') from post
```

I tried DATE_FORMAT but the issue still the same. Do you have any workaround for this issue to prevent any changes of year.

EDIT: the replace is use to remove ',' as the date found in timeposted is "31-02-2010, 04:25 PM"

Thanks,
Keith

Comment: What is the `REPLACE(LEFT(...))` stuff for?

Comment: Can you show us an example of what's in the column now? Your code looks like you're either doing MySQL's job for it or you other characters in the same column

Comment: `str_to_date('31-02-2010, 04:25 PM', '%d-%m-%Y')` gives me `2010-02-31`, so show **EXACTLY** what the query's working with.

Comment: Hi, Thanks MarcB. I thought need to manipulate the string to extract out the date so that str_to_date can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem is caused by the incorrect format string that you used in `STR_TO_DATE()`.

Instead of

```
'%d-%m-%y'
       ^^
```

use

```
'%d-%m-%Y'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/593f2/4)** demo

---

Now as MarcB already commented you don't need all these string manipulations. Just do

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(timeposted, '%d-%m-%Y') timeposted
  FROM post
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/593f2/5)** demo

Comment: "2011" in century mode is "20", which is 2020.