# Curdate() value changing in MySql

Tags: mysql

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I've only been learning MySql for 4 days.

I keep getting different `Year(Curdate())` value which is stopping my code from working.

It keeps giving me Year value which is 3 years plus. I even added an extra column to check if the `Year(Curdate())` value is correct.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: str\_to\_date mess up the year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643468/mysql-str-to-date-mess-up-the-year)

Comment: But I checked the exact code under the column "Free" and its giving 2017. But when I use the same code Year(Curdate()) for Column DOOB it gives 2020. I even tried Year(Now()), both giving 2020 at DOOB

Comment: Did you even check the link I posted?

Comment: Post your code, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format says:

```
%Y  Year, numeric, four digits
%y  Year, numeric (two digits)
```

There's a difference between the capital `%Y` and lower-case `%y`.

`YEAR(CURDATE())` always returns a four-digit year: **2017**

But your date format is trying to read a two-digit year, so it only reads **20**, and applies it to the current century, therefore it returns the year **2020**.

Comment: Thanks a lot bud.. I've been learning MySql for less than a week and thought I was getting tha hang of it but this problem has been driving me nuts. Thanks a lot. I'll keep this in mind in the future

Comment: If you have questions about a particular function or feature in MySQL, keep in mind the documentation is free and is actually quite comprehensive. Get into the habit of looking things up. I've been using MySQL at every one of my jobs since 2000, and I still refer to the manual nearly every day, to confirm details of syntax or usage.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice I will follow it. Just an added question what kinds of job can I find with MySql and do I need to learn anything else.. I only know html and css

Comment: MySQL is just one piece of a large puzzle. You really can't use MySQL alone to produce HTML or web pages. You need some programming language. I like Python, but there are other good options like Java, JavaScript (no relation), and Ruby. I wouldn't bother with PHP, unless you want to develop WordPress plugins.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. I'll start looking into them. Probably move onto javascript after. Any idea how long i should spend learning MySql before moving on. Currently spending around 3-5 hrs daily

Comment: It all depends on how deep you want to study it. You can get basic things done after about a month, but there's always more to learn. You might like to read this blog: http://norvig.com/21-days.html, by Google Director of Research Peter Norvig.